# How to select a distinct list where a single reference has 2 sub-references but also has more than 1 of each sub-reference value

Tags: sql, db2, distinct, having-clause

I am trying to select a distinct list of TRMANE, TRATSA where there is more than one TRASTA of different values associated to a TRMANE.

Here is an extract from the table; WHTRANP

```
TRMANE   TRASTA
56819     5   
56819     5   
56819     4   
56833     5   
56833     4   
56844     5   
56844     4   
56880     5   
56880     5   
56880     4   
56880     4
```

N.B. - As you can see from the above, it's possible there are multiple TRASTAs of the same value against the TRMANE, I think this is what is causing me issues.

Ideally I'd just end up with;

```
TRMANE   TRASTA
56819     5   
56819     4   
56833     5   
56833     4   
56844     5   
56844     4   
56880     5   
56880     4
```

If I do this;

```
SELECT TRMANE, TRASTA   
  FROM WHTRANP           
WHERE TRMANE <> 0        
 GROUP BY TRMANE, TRSTA
 HAVING COUNT(TRASTA) > 2
 ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```

It returns a distinct list of manifests regardless of them having 2 TRASTAS or not - i.e.;

```
TRMANE   TRASTA
     4     5   
     5     5   
     7     5   
     8     5   
     9     5   
    10     5   
    11     5   
    13     5   
    14     5   
    15     5   
    16     5
```

Where as this;

```
SELECT TRMANE as TRMANE, TRASTA AS TRASTA
  FROM WHTRANP                           
WHERE TRMANE <> 0                        
 GROUP BY TRMANE, trasta                 
 HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT TRASTA) > 2       
 ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```

Yields no results.

Comment: Do you just want distinct pairs of _everything_?  Distinct pairs where there wasn't duplicated data, but multiple of the same `TRMANE`?  Distinct pairs only where there was a duplicate `TRMANE, TRASTA` pair?  Why do you need this data- why not just de-dup the table?

Comment: There are no duplicates in the table, there are 90 columns in total that make each row distinct - I was just showing that it's possible that there could be more than 1 TRASTA of a single type per TRMANE because I think this affects the count function.

I would like a list that ONLY shows TRMANE's that have more than 1 unique TRASTA associated to them.

Comment: ...I seriously doubt that your actual (natural) **key** is 90 columns wide.  My guess is ~4: Warehouse/Store, Register, and Date/Time/Timestamp (and/or Date + Receipt Number).  Anything above about 5 starts getting really unwieldy, and you probably need to extract to another table.  Of course, dealing with old flat(er)-files changes things a bit, but even then keys aren't usually that wide...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is looking for those rows where the `trMane` is linked to multiple (unique) `traSta`s.  On it's own, this is easy:

```
SELECT trMane
FROM WHTranP
GROUP BY trMane
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT traSta) > 1
```

The problem of course is getting out all those `traSta` values.  The grouping removes our ability to output them (barring a windowing function being available), so we need to do something else: join back to the table again.

```
SELECT DISTINCT WHTranP.trMane, WHTranP.traSta
FROM WHTranP
JOIN (SELECT trMane
      FROM WHTranP
      GROUP BY trMane
      HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT traSta) > 1) Multiples
  ON Multiples.trMane = WHTranP.trMane
ORDER BY WHTranP.trMane, WHTranP.traSta
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0fabd/3/0)</kbd>

... by joining back to the list we generated earlier, now all we need to do is remove duplicate `traSta` values, which the outer `DISTINCT` handles for us readily.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you version of DB2 supports Windowed Functions:

```
select *
from 
 (
   SELECT TRMANE, TRASTA, -- distinct combinations
       COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY TRMANE) AS cnt  -- number of rows per TRMANE
     FROM WHTRANP           
   WHERE TRMANE <> 0        
   GROUP BY TRMANE, TRSTA
 ) as dt
WHER cnt > 1 -- more than 1 distinct values
ORDER BY 1, 2 DESC
```

Comment: Gives an error on (PARTITION BY...

Says;

Token ( was not valid. Valid tokens: , FROM INTO.

Would appear it doesn't support windowed functions - it's an iSeries STRSQL command.

Comment: @RDKells - depending on iSeries version, it _does_ support (a subset of) windowing functions, but not using them with aggregate functions (like `COUNT(...)`).